# How to Make Function using OOP

Tags: c++, function, oop

Anyone can help me to make function using OOP? How to be able to make the function of finding the average of height of students with OOP?

```
class Person
{
    //data members
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
        int height;
        float weight;
 
    //member functions
    public:
        void setPerson(string n, int a, int h, float w)
        {
            name=n;
            age=a;
            height=h;
            weight=w;
        }
        void setName(string n) { name=n; }
        void setAge(int a) { age=a; }
        void setHeight(int h) { height=h; }
        void setWeight(int w) { weight=w; }
 
        string getName() {return name;}
        int getAge() {return age;}
        int getHeight() {return height;}
        float getWeight() {return weight;}
 
};
 
int main()
{
    Person p[100];
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    string name;
    int age;
    int height;
    float weight;
 
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        cin >> name >> age >> height >> weight;
        p[i].setName(name);
        p[i].setAge(age);
        p[i].setHeight(height);
        p[i].setWeight(weight);
    }

    ..............
```

my input are :

> 3   (number of person)

> jason 20 185 70.50 (name age height weight)

> emma 19 165 55.55

> yerry 25 164 65.10

output :

> 171.33

Comment: As your class is only for a single person, it makes non sense to have a member function computing the average height. Either you use a normal function without another layer of OOP or you implement a new class (e.g. `People`) around an array of `Person`s (I would recommend using `std::vector<Person>` instead of an static array as data member).

Comment: Unrelated: Prefer to have functions that operate on an object over getters and setters that allow outsiders to directly modify the object. If you have `private` variables with `public` getters and setters that do nothing to restrict access to the variables, prevent outsiders from inputting bad values, or some other value-added behaviour, you've effectively made the variables `public` again.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `Person`s recorded, it's just a matter of calculating the average height. It should not be a member function of `Person`, as the class is intended to represent a single `Person`. An average height is not a property or action taken on/by/to a single `Person`, so we just calculate it in `main()`.

I've noted changes that I made to your code.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Person {
  // data members
 private:
  std::string name;
  int age;
  int height;
  float weight;

  // member functions
 public:
  // CHANGE: Change function to constructor
  Person(std::string n, int a, int h, float w)
      : name(n), age(a), height(h), weight(w) {}
  void setName(std::string n) { name = n; }
  void setAge(int a) { age = a; }
  void setHeight(int h) { height = h; }
  void setWeight(int w) { weight = w; }

  std::string getName() { return name; }
  int getAge() { return age; }
  int getHeight() { return height; }
  float getWeight() { return weight; }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Person> p;  // CHANGE: Switch from C-array to std::vector
  int x;
  std::cin >> x;
  std::string name;
  int age;
  int height;
  float weight;

  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    std::cin >> name >> age >> height >> weight;
    p.emplace_back(name, age, height,
                   weight);  // CHANGE: Take advantage of vector functionality
                             // to build Person directly into vector
  }

  // ADDITION: Calculating average height, std::for_each is subjective here,
  // this could have easily been a range-based for loop.
  double avgHeight = 0.0;
  std::for_each(p.begin(), p.end(), [&avgHeight, size = p.size()](auto person) {
    avgHeight += static_cast<double>(person.getHeight()) / size;
  });

  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << avgHeight << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
171.33
```

`std::for_each` may look goofy, but it's literally just summing heights and dividing by the number of `Person`s. Like I noted, it could also just be a range-based for loop. I prefer the range-based for loop in this case; I only have `std::for_each()` because it was a quicker change from my failed attempts at coercing `std::reduce` to work.

```cpp
double avgHeight = 0.0;
for (auto i : p) {
    avgHeight += static_cast<double>(i.getHeight()) / p.size();
}
```

The type of `i` would be better specified as `const auto&`, but your getters are not marked as `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parent struct for Person (call it Individual or something) that has a vector pointer as a member variable. For example, `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double> > Students ( new std::vector<double>() );` The struct would have all the public functions that Person has as pure virtual functions.

Then, add a new void function to Person that derefs Students, and pushes back the height of a new student. Next, you add another function (returning a double or float) that loops through Students to take the sum of the students' heights, and divides it by the size() of the vector.

All Person objects will have pointers to a single Students vector, so every time you push back the height of a new student, it will go to the same place.